# Reactive forms valueChanges method fires twice for one change on input fields

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

Am working in angular app, where used the valueChanges method to detect the changes. like :

```
this.MyFrm.controls['is_applicable'].valueChanges.subscribe(values => {
  this.mainFunc()       
});
```

But it trigger this function twice, To solve this, I have used debounceTime. like :

```
 this.MyFrm.controls['is_applicable'].valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(0),distinctUntilChanged(),takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(values => {
   this.mainFunc()
 });
```

But now problem is occur that valueChanges trigger after some time, that break my code flow.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. You sure you don't have 2 subscriptions open? In the first sample I don't see you unsubscribing, so each time you reload your page a new subscription is created. If this still is an issue, please reproduce the issue in for example a stackblitz.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to take only first response and keep listening for changes on the Reactive Form with **distinctUntilChanged()**, you can use throttleTime(500), this will emit the first value and then ignore next response for 0,5s.

```
this.MyFrm.controls['is_applicable'].valueChanges
    .pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      throttleTime(500),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    )
    .subscribe(values => {
      this.mainFunc()
 });
```

EDIT: Your form field 'is_applicable' for some reason has two Subscribers and that's why is occur to return two times same response.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [distinctuntilchanged](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged) which is one of the rxjs operators. It will return unique values only.

```
 this.MyFrm.controls['is_applicable'].valueChanges.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(values => {
    this.mainFunc()
 });
```

Comment: I have already used it , just forgot to mention. I have updated the question

Comment: If it detects changes once by using distinctUntilChanged but still delayed, remove debounce & just use distinctUntilChanged.

Comment: I have used distinctUntilChanged only, so called valuechanges method called twice time.